# Calcular el factorial de la posición 4 de un array

Tags: java, array

El ejercicio es: Mediante un Array unidimensional, llenarlo con N valores según el usuario. Después mostrar el numero que se encuentra en la posición numero 4 y el numero que este en esa posición realizar su factorial

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Dame el numero de elementos del arreglo");
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int iFactorial = 1;
        int A [] = new int[N];
        for (int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            System.out.print("Dame el valor de la posicion ["+(i+1)+"] del arreglo A: ");
            A[i]=sc.nextInt();
                if(i==4){
        }
        }
        System.out.print("El elemento de la posicion [4] es:"+A[4]);
                for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
                    if(i==4){
                        for(int i=A[4];i<=A[4];i++){
                            iFactorial = iFactorial * i;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(iFactorial);
    }
}
```

Mi error esta en lo ultimo de como hacer el factorial del numero que se encuentra en la posición numero 4. ¿Podrían ayudarme en esa parte? o darme un ejemplo por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el **for** que calcula factorial **i** debe bajar (restar 1 en cada iteración) y la condición debe ser i > 1

Tu código

```
        for(int i= A[4]; i<=A[4]; i++)
```

Corrección

```
         for(int i =A[4]; i > 1 ; i--)
```

ejemplo si el valor en A[4] es 3

```
Iteración 1
i = 3 
factorial = 1
factorial = 1 * 3 (3)

Iteración 2
i = 2
factorial = 3
factorial = 3 * 2 (6)

Iteración 3 
i = 1  fin (lo podrías multiplicar por uno pero es innecesario )
factorial 6 (valor final)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es cierto el for tiene que ir descendentemente como lo hiciste en la explicación muchas gracias ya solo lo ajuste a mi programa y ahora esta excelente 
Saludos!!

Comment: @Edy1999YT, el  error no está en si el for es creciente o decreciente pq de hecho puede ser de las dos formas, el error está en que el for se está ejecutando una sola vez estas diciendo for(int i = a[4]; i<=a[4];i++), estas diciendo que vaya desde a[4] hasta a[4],  estas iterando con el mismo número, ej si a[4] fuese 5, estarías haciendo un for desde 5 hasta 5, y no de 1 hasta 5, o de 5 hasta 1

Answer (score 1):

El **factorial** se calcula multiplicando el número por todos los números que le anteceden hasta llegar al 1.

Puedes usar un **algoritmo iterativo** o **recursivo**.

**Algoritmo iterativo**:

```
int factorial = 1;

for(int i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
{
   factorial = factorial * i;
}
```

Hacemos un **ciclo for** desde 1 hasta el número y vamos multiplicando **factorial * i** y almacenando en la misma **variable factorial**.

Si quisiéramos hallar el factorial de 5 en pocas palabras lo que sucedería es:

```
factorial = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5;
```

**Método recursivo**:

Los **algoritmos recursivos** se dividen en dos partes: paso base y paso recursivo.

Una **función recursiva** es aquella que se llama a ella misma y consiste en resolver un problema a partir de casos más fáciles.

```
public int Factorial(int n)
{
   if(n == 1)
      return 1;//Este es el caso base
   return n * Factorial(n-1);      
}
```

La recursividad es un poco más difícil de entender, pero aumenta la legibilidad del código  te sugiero que investigues más sobre esto en internet.

Comment: Como el q me dio el voto negativo lo hizo pq le dio la gana, pues pq a mi me da la gana elimino mi respuesta y la vuelvo a poner

Comment: A veces pasa eso, dan su voto sin leer la respuesta